# Problematic for loop conversion from MATLAB to Python

Tags: python, arrays, matlab

I am converting some code from MATLAB to Python, and I have encountered an issue I can't resolve. When iterating over the For loop in the section of code, my for loop is spitting out repeated values, that are also incorrect. I believe this has to do with my definition of "x" and "z", but I am not quite  Here is my Python script and the matrices D2A1 and D2A2 are giving the repeated blocks of incorrect values.

```
import sys
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
import scipy.special as scl
import numpy.matlib as mat
###
#np.set_printoptions(threshold = sys.maxsize)
##
###Constants and Parameters
w = np.array([.09,.089])
a = np.array([0,3]) 
coup = np.array([w[0],0])/10
dE12 = -2*w[0] 
gs = np.array([0,0]) 
ws = w**2
alpha  = a[0]*ws[0]/a[1]/ws[1]
dEp = (dE12+a[0]**2*ws[0]/2+a[1]**2*ws[1]/2)/a[1]/ws[1]
ac = np.array([0,0],dtype = 'float')
ac[0] = alpha*dEp*ws[1]/(ws[0]+alpha**2*ws[1])
ac[1] = dEp - alpha*ac[0]
iS = 0 ## starting state
z0c = gs[1]
x0c = gs[0]
Mx = 128*2
Mz = 128*2
N = 2
dt = 0.05

#Now we need grid lengths L[1x1]
Lx = 10
Lz = 10
LxT = Lx*2
LzT = Lz*2
#x0-z0 = z0[1XM] = Grod of M points from 0 to L
x0 = np.array([np.linspace(-Lx,Lx,Mx)])
z0 = np.array([np.linspace(-Lz,Lz, Mz)])
x0op = np.transpose(np.matlib.repmat(x0,Mz,1))
z0op = np.matlib.repmat(z0,Mx,1)

## For loop over matricies

VDI = np.zeros((2,2),dtype = 'complex')
D2A1 = np.zeros(((2,Mx*Mz)),dtype = 'complex')

D2A2 = D2A1
V1 = D2A1
V2 = V1
VP1 = V1
VP2 = V1

for ig in range(Mz):
    for jg in range(Mx):
        z = z0[0,ig]
        
        x = x0[0,jg]
###Diabtic Matrix###
        VDI[0,0] = (w[1]*z)**2/2+(w[0]*x)**2/2
        VDI[1,1] = (w[1]*(z-a[1]))**2/2+(w[0]*(x-a[0]))**2/2+dE12
        VDI[0,1] = coup[1]*(z+ac[1])+coup[0]*(x+ac[0])
        VDI[1,0] = VDI[0,1]
###Adiabatdization###
        [VDt, U] = np.linalg.eigh(VDI)
        VDt = np.array(VDt).reshape(2,1)
        VDt = np.diagflat(VDt)
        UUdVP = np.array([U@sp.linalg.expm(-1.j*dt*VDt)@U.T])
        V = U@VDt@U.T
        ixz = jg+(ig-1)*Mx
        D2A1[:, ixz] =  np.conj((U[:,0]))
        D2A2[:, ixz] =  np.conj((U[:,1]))
print(D2A1)
```

Below is the MATLAB loop I am trying to recreate.

```
 VDI=zeros(2,2);
D2A1=zeros(2,Mx*Mz); D2A2=D2A1; V1=D2A1; V2=V1; VP1=V1; VP2=V1; 
for ig=1:Mz,
   for jg=1:Mx,
    z = z0(ig); x = x0(jg);
 % diabatic matrix   
    VDI(1,1) = (w(2)*z)^2/2+(w(1)*x)^2/2;
    VDI(2,2) = (w(2)*(z-a(2)))^2/2+(w(2)*(x-a(1)))^2/2+dE12;
    VDI(1,2) = coup(2)*(z+ac(2))+coup(1)*(x+ac(1)); VDI(2,1)=VDI(1,2);
 % adiabatization     
    [U,VDt]=eig(VDI)  ;
    [VDt Ind]=sort(diag(VDt)); U=U(:,Ind);
    UUdVP=U*diag(exp(-1i*dt*VDt))*U';
    V=U*diag(VDt)*U';
    ixz = jg + (ig-1)*Mx;
    D2A1(:,ixz) = conj(U(:,1)); D2A2(:,ixz) = conj(U(:,2));   
    
end; end;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the guidance,  I have edited the post

Comment: Can you tell the difference between `x = x0[0,ig]` and `x = x0(jg)`?

Comment: Yes, I believe so. For x = x0[0,ig] we are choosing the ig^th column from the 0^th row, while x=x0(jg) means that we are looping over the jg^th column from the array x0. So I presume that this is my issue. How would I correct this?

Comment: It seems like you did fix this. Does this change fix your program?

Comment: Not explicitly,  my attempt to fix this was `for ig in range(Mz):
    for jg in range(Mx):
        z = z0[ig]
        x = x0[jg]` while removing np.array from x0, z0. But this does not generate the correct values for D2A1/D2A2. In MATLAB the first two rows of D2A1 should be `-0.843867754242161
-0.536551221553257` while my Python code is generating -0.52307016, 0.85228963

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed. Error was in the definition of matrices to be generated. From what I gather in Python you must specifically define each array, while in MATLAB you can set matrix equivalences and run them through a for-loop.